# Spring. Планировщик задач. Задача запускается дважды

Tags: spring, spring-boot, task, планировщик-задач

Помогите разобраться что происходит! Создаю простое Spring-boot приложение.

Есть только один класс:

```
@Component
public class Example {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    private void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

в `context.xml` указываю бин:

```
<bean class="com.example.Example"/>
```

**ПРОБЛЕМА**
При старте проекта, насколько я понял, создаются объекты всех указанных в context.xml бинов и, соответственно, автоматически запускается Задание `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)` (Этого запуска обычно не происходит если убрать бин из `context.xml`).

После того как проект запустился, Задание `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)` срабатывает как полагается ему сработать. И получается на выходе два приветствия:

```
Hello!
Hello!
```

Бин должен быть в `context.xml` т.к. он участвует в автосвязывании (`@Autowired`) в другом классе.

Почему так происходит?

Стоит ли избегать добавления Планировщика задач к методам класса, указанного в ContextApplication? Может стоит создавать отдельный класс для работы с Зданиями и вызывать из него все что необходимо?

Comment: *> Бин должен быть в context.xml т.к. он участвует в автосвязывании (@Autowired) в другом классе.* Для этого достаточно аннотации @Component (которая у вас и так уже стоит) и включенного автоскана.

Comment: @Nofate спасибо! понял ошибку